# pgf-umlcd : text width error in class diagram

Tags: pgf-umlcd

Trying to draw a package classes diagram with `pgf-umlcd`, I have got an error because of `text width` parameter for the class width, I don't know which package I need to solve the problem.

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{package}{Package}
\begin{class}{Class}[text width=5cm]{1 ,1}
...
\end {class}
\end{package}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: My recommendation: If you do not have too many class diagrams already switch to the more powerful tikz-uml package (https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/).

Comment: if you think so, I will switch them, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helps if you put the optional argument in the correct place, i.e. immediately after `\begin{class}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{package}{Package}
\begin{class}[text width=5cm]{Class}{1 ,1}
...
\end {class}
\end{package}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```